# Password protected folder not visible

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

I am trying to run an internal apache server. I am trying to make a homepage like http://internalserver/  This will have a number of files and folders. I am trying to password protect one of these sub-folders. I am using .htaccess for this.

My problem is that, after this has been done, my password protected subfolder is not visible in my base directory http://internalserver/
If I access http://internalserver/passwordprotected/ directly from the browser, I am able to get the password prompt and subsquently navigate
 I am running apache2.4 on Ubuntu14
I would like to be able to see the passwordprotected directory listing, and when trying to access it, get the password prompt

Comment: What have you tried thus far to get this working? Did you research how to show directory contents in Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add ShowForbidden

http://www.rfc3092.net/2013/09/apache-doesnt-show-protected-folders-foo/

> IndexOptions +ShowForbidden

Do restart Apache after adding this line.

For reference:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#IndexOptions

> ShowForbidden If specified, Apache httpd will show files normally
>   hidden because the subrequest returned HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED or
>   HTTP_FORBIDDEN

Comment: This worked for me, I had given IndexOptions in the directory which was protected not its root folder